# GeoKettle Spatial Reference Transformations

Tags: coordinate-system, geokettle

I'm attempting to use GeoKettle to transform some Ordance Survey shapefiles from British National Grid projection into WGS84 EPSG:4326; however, there is a discrepancy in the location of approx 80m between the output from GeoKettle compared to the same data that has been reprojected in ArcGIS or QGIS.

In the SRS Transformation dialog the 'source spatial reference system' is correctly detected as British National Grid (EPSG 27700) and then I select EPSG 4326 from the right-hand pane so I don't see anything that I could be doing wrong - is this a known error?

Comment: You have to be careful with British National Gird to use the correct transformation (OSTN02). Not familiar with GeoKettle so not sure if you are able to use custom transformation settings...